# Orthogonal complement to a set in $L^2[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis

Given the set $F=\{f\in C[0,1] | f(t)=0, \forall t\leq 1/2\}$ of the Hilbert space $L^2[0,1],$ how do I find the orthogonal complement?

Answer (score 1):

For a function $g$ to be orthogonal to $F$ we need $\left \langle f,g \right \rangle = 0\ \forall f \in F$ which reduces to
$$\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 f(t)g(t)\text{d}t = 0$$ This means we must have $g|_{[\frac{1}{2},1]}= 0$ (since $g$ is orthogonal to each $f(t)=\delta(t-\xi)$ for $\xi \geq 0.5$), and of course $g$ can be whatever it wants in $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$.

Edit: Dirachs are not in $L^2$ so that proof needs a different reasoning. This can be emulated by using indicator functions of intervals with size $2\epsilon$ around each $x$, and using the integral mean value theorem.

Comment: Orthogonality actually holds for a slightly larger set of functions: We only need $g$ to be zero *almost everywhere* on $[1/2,1]$.